# How can I store value inside Telerik Grid in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using `Telerik grid` in ASP.Net MVC, I want to store "Key" in `ViewBag/Session` and pass it to controller, "Key" is bound with column of `telerik grid`.
How can I achieve it?

@(Html.Telerik().Grid()
            .Name("Grid")

```
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.Key).Width(140);
        })
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("OnRowDataBound"))
        .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
                Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                    .Name("TabStrip_<#= Key #>")
                    .SelectedIndex(0)
                    .Items(items =>
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Resolution").Content(
                                Html.Telerik().Grid<AnotherModel>()
                                    .Name("Resolutions_<#= Key #>")
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(f => f.CreatedDate).Width(140).Title("Date");
                                        columns.Bound(f => f.Name).Title("Name");                                      
                                    })
                                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                        .Select("MyControllerAction2", "MyController",PASS_KEY_HERE_EACH_TIME))
                                        //Here instead of PASS_KEY_HERE_EACH_TIME, I need 'Key' to pass here of FirstModel
                                    .Pageable()
                                    .Sortable()
                                    .Filterable()
                                    .Scrollable()
                                    .ToHtmlString()
                                    );

                    })
                    .ToHtmlString()
        ))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("MyControllerAction1", "MyController"))
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
        .Sortable()
    )
```

controller I want to call each time at binding

```
    public ActionResult MyControllerAction2(string myKey)
        {
            var test = new List<Data>();
            ProjectDetail projectDetail = new ProjectDetail();
            test = projectDetail.GetData("KEY-123");
            // Actually I want to use Key here which is passed in View at DataBinding(),
                so that I can get all data I need
            return View(new GridModel(test));
        }
```

Comment: What is scenation when you want to send this to controller? Do you want to send current value of Key for selected row in grid?

Comment: Yes, each time in the column, I want to send "Key" to controller. And is it possible to send with javascript function? from                                                                          `.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("OnRowDataBound"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this value in your `OnRowDataBound(e)` javascript function:

```
function onRowDatabound(e) {
    var currentKey = e.dataItem.Key;
    //send currentKey to controller 
}
```

**Update:**

If you have master:detail, you can use next:

```
.DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate("<div style='float:left' class='e-function-grid-detail' data-Key='<#= Key #>'>" +
                Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                    .Name("TabStrip_<#= Key #>")
                    .SelectedIndex(0)
                    .Items(items =>
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Resolution").Content(
                                Html.Telerik().Grid<AnotherModel>()
                                    .Name("Resolutions_<#= Key #>")
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(f => f.CreatedDate).Width(140).Title("Date");
                                        columns.Bound(f => f.Name).Title("Name");                                      
                                    })
                                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                        .Select("MyControllerAction2", "MyController"))
                                    .Pageable()
                                    .Sortable()
                                    .Filterable()
                                    .Scrollable()
                                    .ClientEvents(ce => ce.OnDataBinding("function(e){ addKeyToRequest(this, e);}")
                                    .ToHtmlString()
                                    );

                    })
                    .ToHtmlString()
        )) + "</div>"
```

and write js function

```
function addKeyToRequest(sender, e) {
        var key= $(sender).closest('div.e-function-grid-detail').data("Key");
        if (e.data == null || e.data == '') {
            e.data = new Object();
        }
        e.data.Key = key;
    }
```

This function is called before post for data to controller and add your key value to post.

Comment: Thanks Kirill Bestemyanov, it's giving all keys', but I forget to mention I need it in another child grid.